# Panel does not expand vertically in a TabPanel

Tags: javascript, extjs, panel, expand, tabpanel

Using Extjs, I've got a TabPanel containing two Panels. Those panels do not automatically expand vertically. All layout are set with type 'fit' and forceFit is true.

**Edit:**

I've updated my code according the Kunal's suggestion.

To describe the interface: you have a tree list containing several nodes. When the user clicks on one of those nodes it opens a tab (calling the function ZombieTab(zombie_ip)) with two sub-tabs (ZombieTab_MainTab and ZombieTab_Commands).

Editing the code with Kunal's suggestion had the following effect: We can see that the ZombieTab_Commands's bottom bars appears at the top of the panel and as a result, all components of the tab are not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the main tab of your, which is ZombieTab, is taking the whole space?

If yes, I would make changes for child panels as

```
ZombieTab_MainTab.superclass.constructor.call(this, {
    id: 'zombie-main-tab',
    layout:'fit',
    title: 'Main',
    items: {
            layout:'border',
            items:[top_bar, logs]
           }
});
```

similarly for other child panel as well.

For the Toolbar in Command Tab, try replacing with normal Ext Toolbar and see the effect.

```
    bbar: new Ext.Toolbar({
        id: 'exploits-bbar-zombie-'+zombie_ip,
        text: 'ready',
        border: false,
        iconCls: 'x-status-valid',
        items : [ { text: 'test'} ]
    })
```

Comment: Thanks Kunal. It didn't completely fix the problem but it does look better. I've updated my post to explain what's going on. Have a look at the screenshot and the new source code i've posted.

Comment: Does the Main Tab looks better?

I tried replacing Ext.ux.StatusBar with Ext.Toolbar and it looks good. Editing my response and try it again.

Comment: The Main Tab is empty for the moment (not yet coded) so I can't really comment on if it looks good or not.

As for the command tab, i get different results depending on the browser. So with firefox, if I open one zombie tab (ZombieTab(zombie_ip)) and click on the command tab, it's gonna render perfectly. But then if I open another one, that last one will have the issue shown in the screenshot.

With Chrome, both the first and second ZombieTab will not render correctly. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Hey Kunal, I just found the problem. It was because the Main Panel was not coded... Thanks for your help. I'll validate your answer.